# Set content length header in java play framework http request

Tags: playframework, multipartform-data, content-length, playframework-webservice

I am using [play 2.5.x ws library](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaWS#submitting-multipart-form-data) 
for a file upload to an internal server.
I have sample code working with apache http/curl/postman. 
But when I try to use ws library some how its failing.
I don't have access to the internal server and its not returning any error message

I have checked the request headers from both requests(apache http/play WS) and I see that "Content length " header 
is missing from WS request. 
I tried to set it with

```
ws.url(url).setHeader().post(Source.from(Arrays.asList(fp,name)
```

but I am getting

```
"Stream has already been consumed and cannot be reset"
```

Is there any way I can set the content length ?. 
Or is there anything else I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not properly documented, but you can [look at the code](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.5.x/framework/src/play-java-ws/src/main/java/play/libs/ws/ahc/AhcWSRequest.java#L520-L533) to understand how `post(Source)` works:

> ```
> // If the body has a streaming interface it should be up to the user to provide a manual Content-Length
> // else every content would be Transfer-Encoding: chunked
> // If the Content-Length is -1 Async-Http-Client sets a Transfer-Encoding: chunked
> // If the Content-Length is great than -1 Async-Http-Client will use the correct Content-Length
> ```

`-1` is the default.

So, currently, it us up to you to set `Content-Length` or make your server accept chunked transfer.